# Is there a way to get Class from Any (when Any is a instance of a object)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'd like to implement a logging module in my app with a generic signature as (shortened):

```
func log(msg: String, instance: Any) {}
```

MY app is made of several frameworks and I'd like the ability to activate/deactivate logging per framework. To tell the framework(bundle) from a class is pretty straightforward, as in:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: SomeClass.self)
```

So what I've tried to do in my func log() is:

```
let instance: Any = SomeClass() // This is for the purpose of explanation
if let theClass = type(of: instance) {
 let bundle = Bundle(for: theClass) // Doesn't work, because theClass is a metaType
}
```

Is there a way at runtime to know if a variable: Any is an instance of a object and to have the AnyClass for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should suffice:

```
let instance: Any = SomeClass()

if let thisClass = type(of: instance) as? AnyClass {
    //is a class

    let bundle = Bundle(for: thisClass)
    print(bundle)
}
else {
    //is not a class
}
```

Infact, as long as you typecast the `instance` object to `AnyClass` properly, you will be able to use it in the `Bundle(for:)`

Comment: @André Hm... but it works for me. Could you confirm that this indeed always fails for you and if so then could you spare a few moments letting me know why you think this isn't working for you. ...just curious

Comment: apologies, did try again in a clean playground and it works as well. Thanks

Comment: @André Super! I was a bit puzzled and intrigued as to why it would fail but thanks for getting back to me. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using Mirror:

```
let paperino: Paperino = Paperino()
let any = paperino as Any
let anyMirror = Mirror(reflecting: any)
let thisClass = anyMirror.subjectType
if let anyclass = thisClass as? AnyClass {
    print(Bundle(for: anyclass).bundleIdentifier!)
}
```